# Is there a method that is called when an outlet is connected in an Interface Builder Plugin?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I have created an Interface Builder plugin and want to be notified when the user connects an outlet at design time so that I can perform some action.

Comment: I've re-written the question as I understand it. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: Joshua Nozzi - Yes, this is right question. Thanks.